# Remove Quotes awk or sed

Tags: string, bash, awk, sed, quotes

I have a CSV file and want to only remove all quotes unless inside of a string.

Example:

```
"I have a file that says "need help" please"
```

I want to remove all double quotes in the text unless inside of double quotes. Example, don't remove the quotes around "need help"

Anyone have a clue?

I'm getting pretty good at `awk` and `sed` commands but this one stumped me.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Post a few lines of representative input with interesting/difficult examples, otherwise you're likely to get a solution that works for that one line and nothing else.

Comment: ... and there you go - first 3 answers posted will not even work for CSV files that contain more than 1 field, e.g. `"a "b" c","d "e" f"` -> `a "b" c,d "e" f`, never mind getting into fields that contain newlines, commas, etc. One particular case we need your input on is `"a","b"` - is that 2 fields separated by a comma or one field with a quoted comma inside it? If the latter how do we know when the `,` DOES separate fields? If the former, how DO you show a double-quoted comma within a field? There's no standard for CSV so we need you to tell us what CSV means to you.

Comment: Could I urge too for an example of actual data displaying the various peculiarities of your file? For example, what should appends for `"I have a file that says "need help", please"` Please note the `,` unfortunately placed just after the `"` ...

Comment: What you posted doesn't have quotes inside of quotes... It has two separate quoted sections ("I have a file that says" and " please") with some unqouted text (need help) in between... Seriously, unless you are using the Unicode characters for left double quote and right double quote, there is no way to uniquely parse arbitrarily nested double quotes...

Comment: Most CSV files use the convention that inside a quoted field, a quote must be doubled. So the field in your question would be represented as `"I have a file that says ""need help"", please"` and the dequoted version would be `I have a file that says "need help", please`. That's pretty easy to handle. If you have a file which was produced with some other convention, then the answer will be quite different. It would also be useful to know whether you have GNU awk or some other, less extended `awk`.

Comment: The data is confidential information and cannot be relieved. I have figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: Please enlighten us with the solution you figured out since several of us put some effort into trying to help you so we are naturally curious. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not do what you want depending on your CSV format and requirements:

```
$ cat file
"I have a file that says "need help" please"
"a "b" c","d "e" f"
$
$ awk -F'","' -v OFS=, '{$1=$1;gsub(/^"|"$/,"")}1' file
I have a file that says "need help" please
a "b" c,d "e" f
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep -Po '".*?"'`:

```
echo 'this is a test "I need help" and "it has to be now"' | grep -Po '".*?"'
"I need help"
"it has to be now"
```

Comment: Sure. You're not answering OP question correctly − at all. You use expected output (for this case) as input; with input `' "I have a file that says "need help" please" '` you output `"I have a file that says "` and `" please"` (see comment to OP from twalberg). Sorry, but that's not a good proposal for me (ah, see also comment from Ed Morton).

Comment: @Qeole thanks for commenting, I understood your point however I can't agree with that, I showed OP how to keep the quoted fields inside a string, and presented a better example that the one he presented which indeed had two sessions instead  quoted field inside string. But anyway getting downvoted is the price you pay for answering unclear questions, Getting more selective from now on :)

Comment: But that's just not what OP wants! OP _does_ want to remove some quotes. While I agree above comments highlighted that fields format for the CSV file used by OP is not clear, the initial purpose is well expressed for me: for each field on a line, delete double quotes if present, unless they are nested quotes. When I read your answer I see “Hey, if you want to extract all quoted parts, here's a way”, and I feel like your proposing another question and its corresponding answer.